# Configuring Chrome Extensions

Tags: windows, deployment, extension, chrome

When deploying Chrome in an organizaiton, extensions can be installed with the [ExtensionInstallForcelist](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

But how do you configure options for these extensions?

E.g. one of the extensions we would like to install is IE Tabs (for some intranet sites). How can we include a predefined list of sites that should use it?

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Customize and Control Google Chrome button" next to the address bar. It should open the settings page. Click the extensions link on the left. You will all extensions listed. If any extensions have configurable options an"options" link will be displayed.

Comment: I need to configure the extension when it's deployed to the clients. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Legacy Browser Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3019558?hl=en) extension instead. It supports configuring the list of sites to use in IE via GPO policy.